# High quality drivers for Huawei E160X modem?

Tags: driver, cellular-data, modem

I am using a Huawei E160X mobile dongle on OS X (10.6.8). I am connecting via Orange in the UK using the driver/GUI which is supplied on the device (it's rebranded Huawei software, I believe). If it helps, it is Internet Everywhere 2.0 (build: 090924.164852).

Unfortunately, this software is terrible. It opens the Orange home page upon every connection, and this "feature" cannot be turned off. It dumps errors every few seconds into the logs, and has a memory leak that means its memory consumption rises to 500MB-1GB if left on for an extended period of time.

I tend to prefer OS-based or open source drivers for modems, since they are less likely to contain phone-home or diagnostic transmission features. However a good googling has not revealed any such thing - any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Addendum: ages ago, I tried using the network settings (e.g. [here](http://blog.evandavey.com/2008/02/how-to-connect-huawei-e220-usb-modem.html)) but that didn't seem to connect successfully. Tips on getting that to work would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You could give [launch2net](http://www.novamedia.de/en/mac-launch2net-premium.html) from Novamedia a try. There is trial version to make sure it works with your hardware. The trial is limited to 90 minutes online time

Comment: My previous web searching did not find that one, so thanks. If I am stuck for a solid solution, I will consider that one.